# Как правильно расчитать координаты для вывода формы

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, vb.net

Подскажите как правильно расчитать координаты для вывода формы, чтобы поместить ее в правом нижнем угру рабочего стола, не закрывая при этом таскбар.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Относительно рабочей области активного виртуального рабочего стола с учетом любого положения таскбара на экране.

```
var x = SystemInformation.WorkingArea.Width - Width;
var y = SystemInformation.WorkingArea.Height - Height;
Location = new Point(x, y);
```

Решение по мотивам этого [вопроса и ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1317235/5796587) с EnSO